# Como fazer upload de multiplas imagens com apenas 1 click?

Tags: jquery, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou estudando upload de imagens e arquivos, e consigo fazer upload de 1 imagem, e mostrar ela na tela, mas tenho interesse em fazer upload de multiplas imagens com apenas um botao, igual a essa aplicaçao web http://www.photojoiner.net/.
Como fazer upload de multiplas imagens?

estou usando asp.net.mvc 5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o plugin jQuery File Upload criado pelo blueimp:

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

É possível instalar o plugin pelo nuget. Basta ir no **Package Manager**, e procurar por **blueimp**. Vai aparecer o próprio plugin, e alguns samples de como usar com o MVC.

Também é possível instalar pelo console. Abaixo as respectivas páginas na galeria do nuget:

- **Plugin:** https://www.nuget.org/packages/JQuery_File_Upload_Plugin/

  ```
  PM> Install-Package JQuery_File_Upload_Plugin
  ```
- **Exemplo:** https://www.nuget.org/packages/JQueryFileUpload_Demo_with_Backload/

  ```
  PM> Install-Package JQueryFileUpload_Demo_with_Backload
  ```
- **Exemplo:** https://www.nuget.org/packages/Backload/

  ```
  PM> Install-Package Backload
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Você também pode indicar no `<input>` o atributo `multiple="true"`, assim poderá selecionar várias imagens ao mesmo tempo.